# Unexpected behavior in scitkit-learn's normalizer

Tags: python, normalization, scikit-learn

I have a pandas array and want to normalize 1 single column, here 'col3'

This is how my data looks like:

```
test1['col3']
1     73.506
2     73.403
3     74.038
4     73.980
5     74.295
6     72.864
7     74.013
8     73.748
9     74.536
10    74.926
11    74.355
12    75.577
13    75.563
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

When I use the normalizer function (I hope that I am just using it incorrectly), I get:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
preprocessing.normalize(test1['col3'][:, np.newaxis], axis=0)

array([[ 0.27468327],
       [ 0.27429837],
       [ 0.27667129],
       [ 0.27645455],
       [ 0.27763167],
       [ 0.27228419],
       [ 0.27657787],
       [ 0.27558759],
       [ 0.27853226],
       [ 0.27998964],
       [ 0.27785588],
       [ 0.28242235],
       [ 0.28237003]])
```

But for normalization (not standardization), I would usually want to scale the values to a range 0 to 1, right? E.g., via the equation

$X' = \frac{X \; -  \; X_{min} }{X_{max} - X_{min}}$

(Hm, somehow the Latex doesn't work today...)

[image]

So, when I do it "manually", I get completely different results (but results I would expect)

```
(test1['col3'] - test1['col3'].min()) / (test1['col3'].max() - test1['col3'].min())


1     0.236638
2     0.198673
3     0.432731
4     0.411353
5     0.527460
6     0.000000
7     0.423516
8     0.325839
9     0.616292
10    0.760044
11    0.549576
12    1.000000
13    0.994840
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not all what `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` does. In fact, it scales its input  vectors to unit L2 norm (or L1 norm if requested), i.e.

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
>>> rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
>>> x = rng.randn(2, 5)
>>> x
array([[ 0.49671415, -0.1382643 ,  0.64768854,  1.52302986, -0.23415337],
       [-0.23413696,  1.57921282,  0.76743473, -0.46947439,  0.54256004]])
>>> normalize(x)
array([[ 0.28396232, -0.07904315,  0.37027159,  0.87068807, -0.13386116],
       [-0.12251149,  0.82631858,  0.40155802, -0.24565113,  0.28389299]])
>>> x / np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
array([[ 0.28396232, -0.07904315,  0.37027159,  0.87068807, -0.13386116],
       [-0.12251149,  0.82631858,  0.40155802, -0.24565113,  0.28389299]])
>>> np.linalg.norm(normalize(x), axis=1)
array([ 1.,  1.])
```

(`normalize` uses a faster way of computing the norm than `np.linalg` and deals with zeros gracefully, but otherwise these two expressions are the same.)

What you were expecting is called [min-max scaling](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler) in scikit-learn.